# Child Table Primary Key Constraint Error in JPA nested object

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Primary Key Constraint error occurs sometimes (not always) in Child object When I persist root object
`em.persist(Parent Object)`
here is my hierarchy of nested object

[image]

Parent and Child Object 1 is Bidirectional OneToMany Relationship and also Bidirectional OneToMany of Child 1 and Child 2, Child 2 and Child 3.
I used `CascadeType.ALL` for Many Side, `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

I format ID inside setter method for all entity.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "MYTABLE_GEN")
@Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
public String getId() {
  return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
  if (id != null) {
    this.id = FormatID.formatId(id); // custom format of ID
  }
}
```

Here is TableGenerator

`@TableGenerator(name = "MYTABLE_GEN", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME",  valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "MYTABLE_GEN", allocationSize = 10)`

Is there any suggestion for error cause.

Comment: Where Is your table generator located?

Comment: Furthermore are you sure the id setter gets call in case you are persisting a new entity, as the id is generated.

Comment: What does your FormatID do, and what value and Entity is causing the issue?  Try removing the FormatID logic or have JPA use field access.  Otherwise this method will cause the getID to return a different id value then was set in the database, resulting in problems with determining if an entity exists etc.